# Why am I getting this NoClassDefFoundError from my code?

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

I have been trying to use a Jar file as a library in my code, and it compiles fine. However, at runtime, I keep getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` message. Why is this happening? I have included the Jar file in the compile path and the runtime path too.

Here is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.(COSDocument.java:51)
>       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.(PDDocument.java:136)
>       at processing.PDFToJPG.main(PDFToJPG.java:58)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:        org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 3 more

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using NetBeans IDE as well as Windows 10

This is my setting for compile classpath:

[[image: This is my setting for compile classpath[1]]

This is my setting for runtime classpath:

[[image: This is my setting for runtime classpath[2]]

EDIT: Thank you for your help, it really worked. All i needed to do was to download the dependencies Jar file, not editing the classpath like what i have been trying to do

Comment: Have you looked at such questions as ["*Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?*"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34413/1364007)?

Comment: I looked at a lot of articles, all of them were about classpaths. Turns out there were a dependency aspect between PDFbox and common-logging that i didn't know about

Comment: Your PDFBox version is outdated. 1.8.10 is current. (Or 2.0 RC2 if you're a really cool person)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need another jars besides the one you have already included. Try to add [common-logging 1.4](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/io/binaries/commons-io-1.4-bin.zip). Apparently, there is a dependency between pdfbox1.8.jar and this jar as stated on their [site](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html).

EDIT: There are more dependencies fontbox and jempbox to take in account as well.

EDIT2: I made a zip with all dependencies needed you can download it [here](http://aurelien.tricoire.free.fr/dependency.zip).

Comment: Thank you, it really helped

Comment: @Le Hoang Long - If my answer was helpfull could you please accept it ?

Comment: Done. Sorry, i didn't know about this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Aurelien's post: it looks like you are missing Apache Commons Logging - and other runtime dependencies.

You might want to consider creating your project as a 'Maven' Project (And Netbeans supports Maven pretty well): and then adding 'pdfbox' as a 'dependency'; this should make life a lot easier for you - since Maven will fetch any other required dependencies.

You can get the 'Maven Coordinates' for the various PDFBox versions from here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox

If you want to build your final project into a single JAR containing all the deps; or to create a separate 'lib' directory of them:  you will have to make some minor changes to the Maven project file ('pom.xml') to do this.

This [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654213/how-do-i-create-a-netbeans-style-jar-with-all-dependencies-in-a-lib-folder) has an example of doing that.