Unable to run jar from cli, poi-ooxml ...xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellSytle ignored
I have a simple java program which creates a pre-formatted excel file from a csv, what I would like to get out of the IDE to run as jar file on a windows host. Within Netbeans it's working since years, but when I hit clean and build to generate the jar then test it from command line with java command then I get the following error:
"Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle"
This is strange to me, because I do not use SS.usermodel.CellStyle, but use XSSF.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle interface. Why does it complain for SS?
Poi and poi-ooxml dependencies both included with the same version 5.0.0 cause I use classes I only found in simple poi.
I'm an enthusiast so it is possible that I forgot something basic, but I really don't know what. Can you help me? :)
Any further details needed?
Further details as per request:

java -jar /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile/target/formatpenaltyfile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle     at
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
at
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)    at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)     at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:365)     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)     ... 7 more

Running in Netbeans:
cd /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.xxx.formatpenaltyfile.FormatterKlass" -Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...
---------------------< com.xxx:formatpenaltyfile >----------------------
Building formatpenaltyfileNew 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
BUILD SUCCESS
Total time:  13.118 s
Finished at: 2024-09-23T19:25:16+02:00
The snapshot is created automatically, but I can create that by right click on the project within Netbeans IDE and click "Clean" and after "Build with dependencies"
Building log:
cd /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" install
--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 2 source files to /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile/target/classes
--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile/src/test/resources
--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
No tests to run.
--- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
Building jar: /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile/target/formatpenaltyfile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
--- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ formatpenaltyfile ---
Installing /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile/target/formatpenaltyfile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/csomabalint/.m2/repository/com/xxx/formatpenaltyfile/1.0-SNAPSHOT/formatpenaltyfile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Installing /Users/csomabalint/Java/formatpenaltyfile/pom.xml to /Users/csomabalint/.m2/repository/com/xxx/formatpenaltyfile/1.0-SNAPSHOT/formatpenaltyfile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
POM.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>formatpenaltyfile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
               <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.xxx.formatpenaltyfile.FormatterKlass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
    <name>formatpenaltyfileNew</name> 
</project>




This is strange to me It's strange to me as well, since that appears to have nothing to do with JNI. I would post the error
verbatim, along with the details of your actual command

OK but you're still not showing how you're running it

OK. That's all quite messy. As a Java dev, you really should have Maven installed separately. Then it should simply be a question of changing to your project directory and doing mvn exec:java. That's it. If you find your IDE is constraining or altering generic ways of using Maven, then don't let it

Thank you @g00se! Tomorrow, I will continue with fresh mind. I will try to install Maven separately. :)

I installed maven separately and ran the jar again and stopped at the next error: "Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (/Users/csomabalint/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository." In pom.xml I found that 3.2.0 is included, however in repository I did not find any 3.2.0 versioned plugin listed here (this was the help link I received from mvn command): https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

I've used NetBeans and [tag:maven] like this for several years; NetBeans v23 is current; verify that you created a [tag:maven] project, seen here, as contrasted with an [tag:ant] project seen here; if you prefer an [tag:ant] library project, a coherent set of dependencies is shown here.

I would also post your pom.xml. Personally I wouldn't use Ant. For one thing, it doesn't naturally create fat jars, and you're going to need one if you want to use your POI from one jar. It would seem that your pom uses local repos, which, again, is not really a good thing as it will simply make your project unportable and difficult to relocate

Hello @trashgod, I checked your reference and yes I have a simple Java Application with Maven. I updated my Java and Netbeans to the latest version, but the only difference is that now I get the same error message earlier at build time in Netbeans not only from the command line. The message now contains plus info: "certificate_unknown) PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
g00se I need the libraries locally cause the server I plan to run the program has not open port to internet.

Plus: I downloaded exec-maven-plugin 3.2.0 source release, unzipped and put to .m2/repository but did not help. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.2.0/

I need the libraries locally cause the server I plan to run the program has not open port to internet. No you don't. You need just a fat jar. Repos are no longer needed when your app is deployed. It might be useful to place your code somewhere public if you can, so we can check it against the pom

Hi @g00se, I created my first gitHub repo and I made this public. I hope you can reach that: https://github.com/Balint9004/Csv2Excel
I also provided input files for the program, data are not real of course, only for testing purposes. By the way, I'm not a Java developer, but I tried my best. I work with SQLs and ServiceNow administration and scripting.

OK, that's not in the right form but try this instead. Unzip it to /tmp and do cd Csv2Excel;mvn clean package. If your csv files are where you say then java -jar target/formatpenaltyfile-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar should work fine for you

A NetBeans [tag:ant] project collects dependencies in the dist/lib folder; in a [tag:maven] project, use the maven-dependency-plugin; either can be deployed.

See also How do I create a Netbeans style Jar with all dependencies in a lib folder?

Thank you guys for your work and help! I am going to try them as soon as I can remove java jdk23 as it seems APache Netbeans is not compatible with that. https://netbeans.apache.org/front/main/blogs/entry/jep-411-deprecate-the-security1/ Removing is not easy as company security policy does not allow users to be part of the sudoer group so I asked help from Helpdesk. But as soon as somehow I get back my playground, I will continue.

@Balint9004: For reference, Java v21.0.x LTS has been stable with NetBeans 2x for the past year; the 3+ years to EOL may give you useful interval.

Hi Guys! Finally I succeded. What I did that I tried out the company suggested tool "Visual Studio Code" which I found really handy. Creating a new maven project automatically means that maven plugin designed for making a jar file is included. I even could keep jdk23 installed and rewrorte my pom.xml to use this version instead of 1.7 which is not supported. Then I searched google to find the way of export the jar out of the IDE. When done, I simply ran the java -jar xy.jar command in my project directory and voilá excel is created easily from command line. Many thanks for both of You! :)

@Balint9004: You can answer your own question.

Although trashgod's comment pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654214/230513 might solve the problem with JDK 8 and Netbeans, the situation changed and I found an alternate solution by using Visual Studio Code, which automatically included the necessary plugin dependency into the Pom file and I only had to export my project and write the runnable jar.

Well I gave you a working solution some time ago now, but the point is you're really looking at this the wrong way around still. It's the Maven part that's important. The IDE you use doesn't really have much to do with it. It's the plugins in the pom.xml that will determine how easily things work out. And they are configured correctly in the one I gave you
